# Is >= really required in this if-condition. Wouldn't == suffice?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is the problem

*Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target with these additional constraints: all multiples of 5 in the array must be included in the group. If the value immediately following a multiple of 5 is 1, it must not be chosen. (No loops needed.)*

Credit for this excellent solution goes to [vikkymandloi](https://github.com/ozelentok/CodingBat-Soultions/blob/master/Java/Recursion-2.java)

```
 public boolean groupSum5(int start, int[] nums, int target)
    {
        if(start >= nums.length)
        {
            if(target == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
        }
        if(nums[start] % 5 == 0)
        {
            if(start < nums.length - 1 && nums[start+1] == 1)
                return groupSum5(start + 2, nums, target - nums[start]);
            return groupSum5(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]);
        }
      if(groupSum5(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]))
        return true;
      return groupSum5(start + 1, nums, target);
    }
```

But I have a question on whether the below condition is really required

```
if(start >= nums.length)
```

I feel the following would be sufficient

```
if(start == nums.length)
```

I understand that the reasoning behind having >= maybe because we are jumping by 2 when the number in the array is divisible by 5. But we are also doing the below

```
if(start < nums.length - 1 && nums[start+1] == 1)
```

Which means that if the array looks like {2,10,5}, for the last element which is 5, although it's divisible by 5, we still would jump only 1 time, and not two. So start would now be 4 which is equal to nums.length. so, at worst case, start can only equal nums.length, but cannot go over it.

EDIT : I've got a few suggestions that the **>=** is necessary when the 'start' is greater than nums.length. I'm not sure such a case can be encountered. From the main function, I would only pass start to be 0. From then on, it just increments by a factor 1, or by a factor of 2 if it's not the last element. So, from the last element, the increase is always by a factor of 1, which means, start==len will always be encountered.

Comment: What if I call the method with `start = 2` and an empty array?

Comment: Never trust user input.

Comment: @Zoltán , zoltan again thanks for the reply. But can you give me an example where start=2 would be called with an empty array.  From the main, I call the function as groupSum5(0,a,n). TEST CASE1 :So, say my array contained only one element and looked like {5}; , then it would still only increment by 1 and not enter the jump by 2 case because nums.length-1 == 0 and start is 0, not less than 0. ----- TEST CASE2 : Say we took an empty array, then start==0 which is the array length, and so it would directly return 1 which is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> But I have a question on whether the below condition is really required
>
> ```
> if(start >= nums.length)
> ```
>
> I feel the following would be sufficient
>
> ```
> if(start == nums.length)
> ```

Using the second line would be a problem when `start` is greater than `nums.length`. The first line has right logic for that use case.

If the initial call to the function is guaranteed to use a value of `start` that is less than `nums.length`, then using

```
if(start == nums.length)
```

will be OK.

Comment: @R Sahu, thanks for the reply, but I haven't got it completely yet. From the main, I call the function as groupSum5(0,a,n). TEST CASE1 :So, say my array contained only one element and looked like {5}; , then it would still only increment by 1 and not enter the jump by 2 case because nums.length-1 == 0 and start is 0, not less than 0.
-----
TEST CASE2 : Say we took an empty array, then start==0 which is the array length, and so it would directly return 1 which is okay.

Comment: the problem is the line after the 'if' statement. It accesses nums[start] which will be an error if start is greater than or equal to nums.length.

Comment: @PepperBoy, before you even get there, I don't know how the line `if(nums[start] % 5 == 0)` will behave when `start` is greater than `nums.length` in Java. I am not familiar enough with Java.

Comment: @RSahu, I'm not sure such a case can be encountered. From the main function, I would only pass start to be 0. From then on, it just increments by a factor 1, or by a factor of 2 if it's not the last element. So, from the last element, the increase is always by a factor of 1, which means, start==len will always be encountered.

Comment: @PepperBoy, in that case, using `if(start == nums.length)` will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want. If you are certain that your start will always be equal to nums and that is the only time it should work then yes, the second one will suffice. However, if it could be both equal OR greater than use the first one.

Bit of discrete math time. In here we are using logic statements. The statement >= reads as Greater OR Equal. Let p = greater, and q = equal.

- v is the OR sign in Discrete Math, ^ is for AND, XOR is exclusiveOR

For statements dealing with the OR logic operator the following truth table holds:

```
p v q; p = T, q = T; True

p v q; p = T, q = F; True

p v q; p = F, q = T; True

p v q; p = F, q = F; FALSE
```

Thus, it will hold for three of the four cases.  Hope it helps. For AND (&&) operator logic, it only holds when both p and q are TRUE. Btw || is the symbol for OR. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. Please see EDIT. I can't think of a condition where  If start would be greater than nums.length

Comment: Hmm, if that's indeed the  case then I suppose you could get away with ==.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the use case. You should consider that your code is going to be used by other people, so you need to make the methods what I'd like to call dummy-proof. When someone gives wrong user input they would never know why.

Especially in this case (usage of recursion) I would make two methods:

```
public boolean groupSum5(int[] arr, int target) {
   // Some fool proof checking goes here
   return recursiveGroupSum5(0, arr, target);
}

private boolean recursiveGroupSum5(int start, int[] arr, int target) {
    // Logic goes here
}
```

When you approach it like this, you control the first call so you don't have to check if start >= arr.length because you know that will never be reached and thus you can use == in this case. I really like the comment given by @Fildor who says:

> Never trust user input.

Because users are unreliable!